# Hard coded nginx memory limit

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Is there a hard-coded memory limit when using Nginx as a reverse proxy?
I don't find any relevant information about this, so I assume there is no limit in nginx itself.

Comment: IIRC the amount of memory nginx can use is not a priory limited and there is AFAIK no directive that allows you te set an overall memory  consumption limit either to override compile time defaults.  But there are many other settings that will all have compile time defaults that you will need to tune when your system gets loaded. Your system may for example be reaching max [`worker_connections`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#worker_connections) or other (implied and/or set at compilation) limits while still having a large amount of  RAM memory free and unused.